# Current overlap in Inductive Smoothing?

Tags: current, inductance, induction

I have the following circuit implemented in the lab :

[image: schematic]

And the output was :

[image: scope trace]

Can anyone explain why the current overlaps here ? I can't make sense of this.

Comment: Wow, that's got to be one of the crappiest scope shots I've ever seen.  If you don't care enough about your problem to do the simple things, why should anyone else here care either?

Comment: You can clearly see the input and output, if you are too bothered by the dust screen then stfu and don't reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy stored in the load inductor forces the total current to be nonzero. When the voltage across the two diodes is equal (i.e., when the input voltage is zero), the load current is shared equally between the two diodes. When the input voltage is close to zero (within ± one diode drop), the current is still shared, but unequally. Outside of that range, one diode carries all of the current.